# Language-specific removal of diacritics from text and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, languages, accents, cjk

I am using XeLaTeX and BibLateX to write papers in the humanities. I routinely use transcriptions of Chinese (pinyin), Korean (McCune-Reischauer), Japanese (Hepburn), Manchu (Norman) etc. In addition, there are occasional references and quotes in European languages that use diacritics, such as French.

Up until now, I've written all my Chinese transcriptions in pinyin with tone marks (´ acute and ` grave accents, ˇ háček, and ¯ macron). However, many journals discourage the use of tone marks in the transcriptions. I'm therefore looking for a way to strip my text of the diacritics for Chinese. As I see it, I face two problems:

1. I want to strip the bibliography-references of the pinyin diacritics without having to reenter them in the .bib file again, and
2. I want to remove only the diacritics in the Chinese transcriptions, not the macrons in Japanese (e.g. Tōkyō), or the typographically identical accents in French (e.g. problème).

Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE:

This is my try with the code kindly provided by PLK below. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me:

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\mainfontCJK}[0]{HanaMinA}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=0.9]{\mainfontCJK}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{\CJKrmdefault}[Scale=0.9]{NanumMyeongjo}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\usepackage[notes,strict,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}}
}
\DeclareNoinit{
  \noinit{\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}}
}

\addbibresource{MY BIBLIOGRAPHY HERE}


\begin{document}

\cite{WeiYuan18422004ShengwuJi}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The citation comes out as usual, with the diacritics (please ignore the strange formatting of a name, I usually use something else to fix that, which I haven't included in this minimal example):

[image]

UPDATE

The bibliography entry used in the example above:

```
@book{WeiYuan18422004ShengwuJi,
    author = {Wèi, 魏源, Yuán},
    title = {Shèngwǔjì},
    titleaddon = {圣武记},
    usere = {Record of the sacred wars},
    publisher = {Yuèlù shūshè},
    date = {2004},
    origdate = {1842},
    address = {Chángshā},
    edition = {\autocap{c}ritical edition},
    maintitle = {Wèi Yuán quánjí},
    volume = {3}
}
```

Comment: My first thought would be to do this with a script and not so much with TeX. Change ō with o and similar can be quite easily accomplished. Bit more a question for stackoverflow in that regard though.

Comment: You should use e.g. `{\^o}` in your bibliography anyway, perhaps the simplest would be to (re)define those accents to just give their arguments. No need to mangle the bibliography that way. For the text itself, I'd create a script for sed (if on a Unixy system) to replace the UTF-8 accented characters. Doing the replacement _only_ for Chinese transliterations is extremely hard, unless marked by something like `\foreignlanguage{chinese}{transliteration here}`. In the later case it is only tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using biber with biblatex (and you probably should be if you need UTF-8 support like this), then this is possible with the biber mapping feature. For example, to strip acutes, graves, macron and hacek from authors, put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this strips them dynamically whilst reading the .bib and so your bib is not modified.

Also, you may want to strip these for sorting and/or generating initials in which case you also add to your preamble:

```
\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{type_names}{\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}}
}
\DeclareNoinit{
  \noinit{\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}}
}
```

The issue of only stripping Chinese should be handled by the .bib having some way of telling Chinese entries from others - perhaps a `HYPHENATION` or `LANGUAGE` field. Then the first code snippet above becomes something like:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=language, match=chinese, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{[\x{300}\x{301}\x{304}\x{30c}]}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this all assumes you are encoding your .bib in UTF-8 (which you can with biber). If you are using TeX macros, then the regexps would be a bit more complex ...

An alternative, using Unicode classes is to remove all Unicode MARK graphemes instead of individual graphemes:

```
\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\p{Mark}}, replace={}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't work for me, I added my example with your code to the question, so as to provide a minimal example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the bibliography file (just that one entry is fine) to the example? I need that to test.

Comment: Sure, it's added!

Comment: I see the problem. It's something I've been meaning to look at in `biber`. I am making the NFD/NFC Unicode boundaries of the code more robust. Nearly done and will update the 1.6 dev version soon. I have your example working now.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Will you post here when the update is done?

Comment: Yes. I'll update here. You'll have to get the biber 1.6 DEV release and the biblatex 2.6 DEV release when ready. They already exist but I have to update biber 1.6 DEV. Should be tomorrow I think.

Comment: You can now download biber 1.6 DEV version from Sourceforge and try this. You'll also need to be using biblatex 2.6 DEV version from Sourceforge. The example now works for me and I've added an example of using Unicode properties like "MARK" for removing all such graphemes. Perl has very good Unicode support in 5.16 and so you have access to all Unicode properties etc.

Comment: Can I get it by updating my TeX Live?

Comment: No, the DEV versions are not in TL - you have to get them from the sourceforge development folders and install manually. It's quite easy - get the correct biber for your platform and just drop it over your existing one. Biblatex install is slightly more complex but normall you just get the TDS version download and unpack it into the texmf-local directory of your TL tree and then run `texhash` to re-create the package index.

Comment: That proved much too complicated for me. Will they be released with Tex Live the next time they release a new version?

Comment: It's more frequent than that - the new versions will in in TL very soon and you will get them via the usual update procedure - it's just that these dev versions haven't been officially released yet.

Comment: New versions of biblatex and biber should be in TL now.

Comment: I want to thank you again for this script, it works for me in the `author` field now. I reduplicated the `\DeclareSourcemap` and added a `title` field as well. But when I copy the `\DeclareSourcemap` again to add `publisher`, `subtitle` etc, the script just stops working and the diacritics stay. Do I have too many `\DeclareSourcemap`? Is there a way to add several fields in one `\DeclareSourcemap`, e.g. `\step[fieldsource={title and author and editor and editora},`? Thanks!

Comment: Just add another `\map{}` to the same `\maps{}` macro.

Comment: Got it. I look at my dozens of cleaned up references and it feels like magic. Thanks again!